# Button not centring in CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I have created a div container and within the container, there is a div box. Inside the box, I have a button that is supposed to be centered at the bottom of the box.

I have searched around and before anyone does the "duplicate post" I have tried everything that they've said. Such as, adding a "display: block;" into my code etc and still it's not centering the button into the middle. I have been messing around with whatever I can think of to try and centering the button but nothing is working.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.box-1 {
  background-image: url();
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 260px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#mainButton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box-1:hover #mainButton {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><button type="button" id="mainButton"> Go To Website </button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try set left: 30%; in #mainButton

Comment: @phucnh Thank you so much!! It worked!! Mind I ask why you used 30%? I am still learning. I'm creating a website for myself to get better :)

Comment: 100% / 2 + 30% / 2 = 30%.

100% / 2 -> 1/2 container width

30% / 2 -> 1/2 button's width

Comment: Does it matter on how things are coded, as long as, it's doing what you want it to do? I believe if an experienced developer looked at my code, they could probably code what I did in a few lines lol.

Comment: Ya! You need more time :)))

Comment: You should not embed the button with an `<a>` link. That's incorrect. Use `onclick` event listener instead.

Answer (score 0):

These three values set properly on your mainButton CSS should solve your issue:

```
width: 40%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-20%;
```

Its key to note what the calculation is here. The left property is centering the item at 50% of the page, and the negative margin-left is offsetting the items position in accordance with its width. Since its width is 40% the negative margin has to be half of this, ie 20%. With this in mind you can adjust the width and the offset if your design changes, better yet using css variables and calc() mean that you could set the width only and the margin would calculate itself.

As an example:

```
left:50%;
--buttonWidth: 40%;
width: var(--buttonWidth);
margin-left:calc( var(--buttonWidth) / -2);
```

```css
.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.box-1{
  background-image: url();
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 260px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#mainButton{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  width: 40%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-20%;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}


.box-1:hover #mainButton{
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">
      <a href="http://www.google.co.uk">
        <button type="button" id="mainButton"> Go To Website</button> 
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, i think this will help u in fixing the issue.

```
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.box-1 {
  background-image: url();
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 260px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}

#mainButton {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.box-1:hover #mainButton {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "left: 0; right: 0;" in #mainButton

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff000;
}
.box-1 {
  background-image: url();
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 260px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#mainButton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
}
.box-1:hover #mainButton {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><button type="button" id="mainButton"> Go To Website </button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's because your button's parent is a link tag. Your button is not a direct child of the flexbox

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Adam you have to delete the <a> tag. Replace it to a button child.